# How is there only 1 div that doesn't shrink together with other divs in a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this HTML body that is to mimic Google's search page. The issue is with the shrinking of the page to test its *flexbox* properties but the **input textbox** is not shrinking at all.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
}

#searchform {
  margin: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#searchform>* {
  flex: 100%;
}

#gform {
  display: flex;
}

body,
input,
button {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

img {
  height: 92px;
  width: 272;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

#sBar {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 534px;
  height: 34px;
  display: flex;
}

input[type="text"] {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: flex;
  flex: 100%;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchform">
  <div>
    <img class="gImage" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google">
  </div>
  <div>
    <form action="https://google.com/search" method="GET" role="search" id="gForm">
      <div id="sBar">
        <span class="material-icons" role="button">&#xe8b6;</span>
        <input type="text" value="" name="q" oninput="cursorDisplay()" id="forClear">
       </div>
       <input type="submit" name="bntK" class="sButton" value="Google Search" aria-label="Google Search">
       <input type="submit" name="btnI" class="sButton" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" aria-label="I'm Feeling Lucky">
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Basically, I've now put "flex" in every div inside **searchform** but textbox still not shrinking.
This is the smallest chrome window size to see the page shrink:

[image: This is the smallest chrome window size to see the page shrink]

Notice that there is still a horizontal scroll due to the textbox.
Any idea on the code as to why my input textbox is not coordinating?

Comment: Please use a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) befor you ask questions. You have an invalid markup that might cause the errors.

Comment: Your input isn't shrinking because you've put a default width on it.
You can use for example ```80vw``` which takes 80% of the 'view width', instead of your ```534px```.

Comment: Please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69540026/how-is-there-only-1-div-that-doesnt-shrink-together-with-other-divs-in-a-flexbo/69540115#69540115). It works properly now.

Comment: @SecretTimes i put 80vw in sBar and removed 534px. it works now. thanks ya'll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of `width: 534px;` set to `#sBar`. Due to this, element will always consukes the width and produces a scroll in low width.

To make it more flexible

Add `max-width: 534px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;` to `#sBar`

`display: flex; width: 100%;` to `#gForm`. There was a typo in css there.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
}

#searchform {
  margin: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#searchform>* {
  flex: 100%;
}

#gForm {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

body,
input,
button {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

img {
  height: 92px;
  width: 272;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

#sBar {
  border-radius: 25px;
  max-width: 534px;
  height: 34px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type="text"] {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: flex;
  flex: 100%;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchform">
  <div>
    <img class="gImage" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
      alt="Google">
  </div>
  <div>
    <form action="https://google.com/search" method="GET" role="search" id="gForm">
      <div id="sBar">
        <span class="material-icons" role="button">&#xe8b6;</span>
        <input type="text" value="" name="q" oninput="cursorDisplay()" id="forClear">
      </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="bntK" class="sButton" value="Google Search" aria-label="Google Search">
  <input type="submit" name="btnI" class="sButton" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" aria-label="I'm Feeling Lucky">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. removed the width and I also added @SecretTimes 's idea of 80vw to #sBar and it works now. thanks ya'll :))))

Answer (score 0):

comment width in "#sBar"

```css
#sBar {
    border-radius: 25px;
    /* width: 534px; */
    height: 34px;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Works, but I think using ```width: 80vw``` is better because then it auto adjusts to the view width of the device. 
With your answer the input will stay very small on desktop.

Answer (score -1):

It's because `#sBar` has width 534px.

Add `max-width: 90%` to your `#sBar`.

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    width:auto;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
}

#searchform {
    margin: 150px 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#searchform>* {
    flex: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#gForm {
    width: 100%;
}

body, input, button {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
}

img {
    height: 92px;
    width: 272;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

#sBar {
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 534px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
}

input[type="text"] {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: flex;
    flex: 100%;
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="searchform">
        <div>
            <img class="gImage" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google">
        </div>
        <div>
            <form action="https://google.com/search" method="GET" role="search" id="gForm">
                <div id="sBar">
                    <span class="material-icons" role="button">&#xe8b6;</span>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="q" oninput="cursorDisplay()" id="forClear">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="bntK" class="sButton" value="Google Search" aria-label="Google Search">
                <input type="submit" name="btnI" class="sButton" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" aria-label="I'm Feeling Lucky">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```